# How to custom theme the google login screen using users.create_login_url

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-account, google-signin

Usually I would just have users login as follows:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

This brings up the following login screen:
[image: login screen]

However we are developing an app designed to have **one account per company rather than one account per person**. Each employee will then login on behalf of the company either through the **website** front end or using the android app on the companies **android** tablet.

One obvious solution is to create a **gmail** account for each company. However it's been decided that having them use a gmail account (and seeing a google login screen) doesn't reflect well on our **brand**.

Is there a way to **customize the login screen to go with our company logo and colours**? Or to somehow make the login process invisible?

If this is not possible I'll probably have to use custom authorization and sessions which wouldn't be as nice as the batteries included google login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up rolling our own auth with the help of this [tutorial](http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/)

It's unlikely google will let you custom theme a google login process.

I also recommend always having one account per user even if they always do actions on behalf of the company.